# WPF, making scrollviewer work with stackpanel programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a scrollviewer to a stackpanel so that I can go up and down with the content of the stackpanel.

All the solutions I've seen are with XAML and I don't want to use XAML, I want to do it just with C#.

I have written this :

```
                    _projectsPanel = new StackPanel();
                    _projectsPanel.Height = 100;
                    _navigationPanel = new ScrollViewer();
                    _navigationPanel.Content = _projectsPanel;
```

This code adds a scrollviewer aside to the stackpanel (alright) but the arrow buttons are locked, I can't go down or up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `StackPanel` is smaller then `ScrollViewer` so there is noting to scroll and scrollbar is disabled by default.

All you need is to change size of `ScrollViewer` and/or `StackPanel` so Height of `StackPanel` is greater then height if `ScrollViewer`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content is larger than 100 pixels of stack panel to enable the scrollbar buttons, then set the [ScrollbarVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
//Use Visible or Auto Enum based on your requirement.
//Visibile to show always and Auto only if its required
_navigationPanel.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Just setting the scrollviewer height to a value smaller than the stackpanel height did the trick. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

set height ScrollViewer _navigationPanel

```
_projectsPanel = new StackPanel();
_navigationPanel = new ScrollViewer();
_navigationPanel.Height = 100;
_navigationPanel.Content = _projectsPanel;
```